Firefox says image download from iCloud contains a virus or malware
I downloaded an image from iCloud, which ends up as a zip file containing a JPEG file and a MOV file.  This is because the iPhone takes a motion image (MOV) over a brief interval of time, and then generates a JPEG still image.
Firefox complained that the file contained malware, which required me to explicitly allow the download.  I then scanned it with with Windows Defender.  All seems fine.
This seems to be due to some weird interaction between Firefox and Windows Defender.  How is it possible for Firefox to get triggered by the download when the AV says it's fine?
After allowing the download, further picture downloads don't trigger the warning.  From the Firefox download history, the message is "This file contains a virus or malware -- iCloud-content.com".
A further search reveals this. Firefox checks the site but not the content.  It defers to "Google’s Safe Browsing service [to see] if the software is safe by sending it some of the download’s metadata."
Furthermore: "Windows users: This online check will only be performed in Firefox on Windows for those downloaded files that don’t have a known good publisher. Most of the common and safe software for Windows is signed, and so this final check won’t always need to happen."
Since I'm not downloading software, Google’s Safe Browsing service isn't being used (according to the above). Furthermore, iCloud is a very well established site.  So it's unclear why Firefox is being triggered.
P.S. I'd like to suggest that even though the root cause seems to be pointing toward Firefox, this is only with investigative digging.  When someone encounters this, it isn't clear what the cause is, and naive first guesses might place the cause as an interaction between Firefox and Windows Defender.  Therefore, I'd like to propose not closing this so that people running into this problem can find this and see where the problem really lies.  Or at least, where it is likely to lie -- Firefox is just a guess and it is still possible that Windows plays into this, even if that is seeming to be less likely at the time of writing this "P.S.".

What exactly is the language Firefox used? I think it may have been more of an "it's a bit suspicious" or "I can't check it for viruses"

I just tried to download multiple photos from the iCloud and no longer get the warning.  My initial approval of the download may have changed something in Firefox. The Firefox download history shows the warning as "This file contains a virus or malware -- iCloud.content.com". It's not "maybe", but "it contains". Very definitive.

Strange. But does it actually say "iCloud.content.com" (not Apple's), or is it "icloud-content.com" (Apple's)?

The latter (Apple's).  I'll correct this in my posted question.  Thanks!

Not familiar with the Firefox feature, but if icloud is declaring a jpeg in a response header and then offers a zip file, this may qualify as "deceptive content" and it halts the download.

OK, thanks.  Something to pay attention to going forward.

The file does not have to be an application for Google’s Safe Browsing to scan it. This is a case of a false positive.

@Ramhound: You could be right about the Google service, but the cited Firefox page says "asks Google’s Safe Browsing service if the software is safe", so Firefox might choose to not to ask the service for non-app files. Or it could be just an inaccuracy in the documentation. I agree that it's a false positive based on my scanning the downloaded zip file, but it would be nice to know the likely cause so that it can be judiciously ignored.

would be nice to get an example, else this isn't too answerable IMO.

I'd like to follow up with an example, but do you mean an example of what causes  the problem?  The only way to reproduce this is if you have an iCloud account, and then it's as simple as downloading a photo.  As an answer, someone earlier posted a confirmation that this happens, but for some reason, it is now gone.

Yep, it's still happening. Thanks for the post. This is so weird. I took a pic with my phone today (iPhone SE, don't judge lol), went to download and got the warning. Then I Saw this thread Here's a screen shot of the initial warning:
 And then this is all it tells me:

So not much info.

Thanks for confirming, Kara G.

You can stop this by going into Settings
Type Download into the search box
Scroll down
and turn off the section:
Deceptive Content and Dangerous Software Protection

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@John Strudwick: I actually found it easier to go into FF's settings and search for Deceptive Content and Dangerous Software Protection.  But I don't want to turn that off because it removes protection from more than just zip files from iCloud.  The fact that others have confirmed the iCloud problem is good enough for me because it assures me it is unlikely to be a real problem, but I scan the zip file just in case. In fact, I would consider the corroboration of this iCloud behaviour, and the likelihood that it is a false positive, to be the answer.
